# How to invert emulator screen in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation

When I created emulator screen in android for Sony Xperia Z resolution it tend to have inverted screen.How can I resolve this issue,please guide me if I had missed anything for it.I have used android:screenOrientation="portrait" in manifest.Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Press `ctrl+f1' to invert it...setting this `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` will set the fixed orientation for your app

Comment: I am using mac & I tried this using fn+ctrl+f1 but its not working..am I missing anything here..

Comment: Try `command+f11` original, it was misspelled sorry for that... `ctrl+f11`

Answer (score 0):

Try **KEYPAD_7** or **Ctrl-F11**...

More shortcuts here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html